# Forward MimeMessage object messages as an regular forward format INSTEAD of an attachment in EML file

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, eml, email-forwarding

Basically i'm trying to structure for forward email and then convert it into EML file.But the original message object `msg` is rendering as attachment instead of normal message in `EML` file. I've tried     `setContent` and `getDataHandler` methods to add it in multipart email but no luck. I really appreciate if any one can help me out on this.

P.S the `msg` object actual content is in `text/html` format and not in `text/plain` .

Thanks.

```
       MimeMessage forward = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

          // Fill in header
          forward.setSubject("Fwd: " + msg.getSubject());
          forward.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
          forward.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress("toemail@ibm.com")); 
          forward.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC,new InternetAddress("ccemail@gmail.com"));  


          // Create your new message part
            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(
                      "<html><body><h1>This is actual message embedded in HTML tags</h1></body></html>",
                     "text/html");

          // Create a multi-part to combine the parts
            MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
          multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

          // Create and fill part for the forwarded content
          messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
          messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(msg.getDataHandler());
          //messageBodyPart.setContent(msg, "message/rfc822");

          // Add part to multi part
          multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

          // Associate multi-part with message
          forward.setContent(multipart);



          // Send message
          Transport.send((Message)forward);
          System.out.println("message forwarded ....");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add the `messageBodyPart` set [Part::setDisposition](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#setDisposition-java.lang.String-) to [INLINE](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#INLINE).

```
 ...
 messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
 messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(msg.getDataHandler());
 messageBodyPart.setDisposition(Part.INLINE); //<-- Not an attachment.
 //messageBodyPart.setContent(msg, "message/rfc822");
 ...
```